# Playing youtube video using HCYoutubeParser

Tags: ios, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using HCYoutubeParser(https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser) to play some videos in my ios app. When I am trying to play some video, it doesn't seem to play it.

The code looks like this:

```
- (void)playVideo:(id)sender
{
    if (_urlToLoad)
    {
        MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:_urlToLoad];
        _mp = player;
        [self presentViewController:_mp animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)submitYouTubeURL:(id)sender {

    [playButton setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_urlOfYoutube];
    activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [HCYoutubeParser thumbnailForYoutubeURL:url thumbnailSize:YouTubeThumbnailDefaultHighQuality completeBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            [playButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            playButton.hidden = NO;

            NSDictionary *qualities = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:url];
            _urlToLoad  = nil;
            _urlToLoad = [NSURL URLWithString:[qualities objectForKey:@"medium"]];
            NSLog(@"%@",[NSURL URLWithString:[qualities objectForKey:@"medium"]]);
            activityIndicator.hidden = YES;

            [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];
}
```

The line that gives the problem is  `_urlToLoad = [NSURL URLWithString:[qualities objectForKey:@"medium"]];`

[NSURL URLWithString:[qualities objectForKey:@"medium"]] returns null..

How do I solve this?

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser/issues/19

Comment: Yes, not sure how to solve that issue...

Answer (score 2):

In my case , I was getting 0 key value pair for

```
NSDictionary *qualities = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:url];
```

Ie , I was getting `qualities` having  0 key value pair.

I found that code in `HCYoutubeParser.m` , in method `+ (NSDictionary *)h264videosWithYoutubeID:(NSString *)youtubeID` a variable `signature` variable was not getting initialized , so I replaced  NSString *signature = nil; with `NSString *signature = @"";`